# Dropzone using div passing files(multiple images) to controller through ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

Im trying to create a dropzone in div with class dropzone,im getting dropone and can load images on it but can't pass it to controller, but data is not passig through jquery to cotroller.... removing files, everything else are working fine..but i can't get the uploaded files , can someone please tell whats the problm is, i wanted to insert multiple  images,

This is div:

```
 <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 48px; bottom: -50px; border-color:white   ">
                <div class="dropzone" id="mydropzone" action="<?php echo URL.'Events/addeventdetails'?>" >
                     <h1 align="center"><i> Drag or Drop Image Here</i></h1>
                 </div>
             </div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone('div#mydropzone', {
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    maxFiles: 15,
    paramName: 'file',
    clickable: true,
    url: '<?php echo URL . 'Events/addeventdetails' ?>',
    init: function () {

        var myDropzone = this;
        // Update selector to match your button
        $btn.click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ( $form.valid() ) {
                myDropzone.processQueue();
            }
            return false;
        });

        this.on('sending', function (file, xhr, formData) {
            // Append all form inputs to the formData Dropzone will POST
            var data = $form.serializeArray();
            $.each(data, function (key, el) {
                formData.append(el.name, el.value);
            });
            console.log(formData);

        });
    },
    error: function (file, response){
        if ($.type(response) === "string")
            var message = response; //dropzone sends it's own error messages in string
        else
            var message = response.message;
        file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
        _ref = file.previewElement.querySelectorAll("[data-dz-errormessage]");
        _results = [];
        for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
            node = _ref[_i];
            _results.push(node.textContent = message);
        }
        return _results;
    },
    successmultiple: function (file, response) {
        console.log(file, response);
        $modal.modal("show");
    },
    completemultiple: function (file, response) {
        console.log(file, response, "completemultiple");
        //$modal.modal("show");
    },
    reset: function () {
        console.log("resetFiles");
        this.removeAllFiles(true);
    }
});
</script>
```

Controller:

```
    $uploaddir = './uploads';

$images = $_FILES;


$data = [];

foreach ($images as $key => $image) {
    $name = $image['name'];
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($name);
    if (move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        $data[$key]['success'] = true;
        $data[$key]['src'] = $name;

    } else {
        $data[$key]['success'] = false;
        $data[$key]['src'] = $name;
    }
}  
 $this->Common_model->form_insertpic('images');
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you declared var myDropzone twice. That might be a problem.
Check if the ajax call is actualy trigered after you upload an image.
Var_dump($_FILES) in your controller to see what's in there.

I've done it this way. Try it like this:

```
let myDropzone= $("#mydropzone");

const myDropzoneImage = {
    paramName: "file", // name used to transfer the file //
    maxFiles: 50,
    maxFilesize: 5,
    resizeWidth: 350,
    resizeHeight: 258,
    thumbnailWidth: 350,
    thumbnailHeight: 258,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictResponseError: "Server not Configured",
    acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.jpeg",
    //previewsContainer: "#your preview container",

    init: function() {
        let self = this;
        let prevImage = "";

        self.options.dictRemoveFile = "Delete";
        //New file added
        self.on("addedfile", function(file) {
            //console.log("new file added ", file);
        });
        // On removing file
        self.on("removedfile", function(file) {
            // put your ajax call for remove
        });

        self.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
            prevFile = responseText.img_id;
        });

        self.on("error", function(file){
            // console.log("File Failed to Upload");
        });

        //Check image width and height
        self.on("thumbnail", function(file) {
            if (file.width > maxImageWidth || file.height > maxImageHeight) {
                file.rejectDimensions()
            }
            else {
                file.acceptDimensions();
            }
        });

    },
    accept: function(file, done) {
        file.acceptDimensions = done;
        file.rejectDimensions = function() { 
            done("Image width or height too big."); };
        }
    }
}

myDropzone.dropzone(myDropzoneImage);
```

And make sure this url `action="<?php echo URL.'Events/addeventdetails'?>"` is correct!

Comment: Noo theres nothing getting in  var_dump($files)... I can't get the values to there